# List of Tensors when single Tensor expected

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

I use concat to get tensors as the input of CNN. But got the error:      List of Tensors when single Tensor expected

```
image_raw = img.tobytes()
image = tf.decode_raw(image_raw, tf.uint8)
image = tf.reshape(image, [1, image_height, image_width, 3])

image_val = image
for i in range(batch_size-1):
    image_val = tf.concat(0,[image_val,image])
return image_val
```

I have searched the answers for these question, add 
   `image_val = tf.stack([image_val],0)` before return, but still get the same error ,why?

```
 **build  environment：**
 TensorFlow version 0.12
 python 3.5
```

Comment: Is image_height or/and image_width is a tensor?

Answer (score 0):

The error `List of Tensors when single Tensor expected`  comes from the fact you wrote `tf.concat(0,[image_val,image])` instead of `tf.concat([image_val,image],0)`.

Comment: this is the different API for tensorflow 0.1 and 0.12, not the answer for this question. Moreover, I have changed the method, but still have the same error.

Comment: @judyzha Please specify which TensorFlow version you use in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check again the type of `image_height, image_width` because sometimes it is necessary to cast these into an integer dtype, e.g. `tf.cast(image_height, tf.int32)`